# Split a Decimal number into a random array where the sum of the numbers equals the split number

Tags: python, decimal

I want to split a decimal number into a random table where the sum of the elements in the array equals the original number

```
# Call a function which receives a decimal number
from decimal import Decimal
from something import split_random_decimal

split_decimal = split_random_decimal(Decimal('10.00'))

print(split_decimal)
# Output: [1.3, 0.7, 1.2, 0.8, 1.0, 1.5, 0.5, 1.9, 0.1, 1.0]

print(sum(split_decimal))
# Output: Decimal('10.00') - The original decimal value
```

Has anyone an idea how I could do this in pure Python without using a library?

> Solved!

Thks for all who have help me, the final beautiful code who saved my life is this:

```
import random


def random_by_number(number, min_random, max_random, spaces=1, precision=2):
    if spaces <= 0:
        return number

    random_numbers = [random.uniform(min_random, max_random) for i in range(0, spaces)]
    increment_number = (number - sum(random_numbers)) / spaces

    return [round(n + increment_number, precision) for n in random_numbers]


number = 2500.50
spaces = 30
max_random = number / spaces
min_random = max_random * 0.6
random_numbers = random_by_number(number, min_random, max_random, spaces=spaces, precision=2)

print(random_numbers)
print(len(random_numbers))
print(sum(random_numbers))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is really specific. Questions where you just ask users to code something for you are not welcome on this site. Try it yourself and if you fail, post your attempt and ask what you did wrong. We want to teach you how to catch fish, not catch them for you every time you are hungry ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with something like:

```
    numberLeft = 10.0
    decList = list()
    while numberLeft > 0:
          cur = random.uniform(0, numberLeft)
          decList.append(cur)
          numberLeft -= cur
```

This implementation would choose higher random numbers at first which wouldn't be that hard to logically change.
numberLeft will never hit exactly 0 so you could do something with rounding. You could also wait for numberLeft to get low enough and that would be your last random number in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import random as r

def random_sum_to(n, num_terms = None):
    n = n*100
    num_terms = (num_terms or r.randint(2, n)) - 1
    a = r.sample(range(1, n), num_terms) + [0, n]
    list.sort(a)
    return [(a[i+1] - a[i])/100.00 for i in range(len(a) - 1)]

print(random_sum_to(20, 3))   # [8.11, 3.21, 8.68] example
print(random_sum_to(20, 5))   # [5.21, 7.57, 0.43, 3.83, 2.96] example
print(random_sum_to(20))   # [1 ,2 ,1 ,4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3] example
```

n is the number in which you are summing to, and num_terms is the length of the string you would like as a result. Also if you look at the last example you can see that if you don't want to specify a "num_terms" you don't have to and it will do that for you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a little under defined: into how many pieces should it be split and how large may any piece be? Should the values only be positive? An approximate solution from what you've said would be to pick a random number of pieces (defaulting to 10) and making the values be distributed normally about the average size of the pieces with a standard deviation of 1/10 of the average:

```
from decimal import Decimal
def split_random_decimal(x, n=10):
  assert n > 0
  if n == 1:
    return [x]
  from random import gauss
  mu = float(x)/n
  s = mu/10
  if '.' in str(x):
    p = len(str(x)) - str(x).find('.') - 1
  else:
    p = 0
  rv = [Decimal(str(round(gauss(mu, s), p))) for i in range(n-1)]
  rv.append(x - sum(rv))
  return rv

>>> splited_decimal = split_random_decimal(Decimal('10.00'))
>>> print(splited_decimal)
[Decimal('0.84'), Decimal('1.08'), Decimal('0.85'), Decimal('1.04'), 
Decimal('0.96'), Decimal('1.2'), Decimal('0.9'), Decimal('1.09'), 
Decimal('1.08'), Decimal('0.96')]
```